# TYPO3 - Call another repository

Tags: php, typo3, fluid

Is it possible to call a function in different controllers? I need to call `FindByCategoryGrouped($catId)` in designRepository.php and `getCategories($catId)` from categoryRepository.php

```
public function listAction() {
    $this->settings['flexform']['showCategory'] ? $catId = $this->settings['flexform']['showCategory']:$catId = $this->settings['listView']['showCategory'];
    // print $catId;
    if (!$catId || $this->settings['flexform']['showCategory'] == '-1') {
        $designs = $this->designRepository->findAll(); 
    } else {
        // $designs = $this->designRepository->findByCategory($catId);
        $designs = $this->designRepository->findByCategoryGrouped($catId);  // THIS
        $categories = $this->categoryRepository->getCategories($catId); // THIS
    }
    // indhold forsvinder hvis næste linje slettes
    $this->view->assign('designs', $designs, "L", $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid);
    $this->view->assign('catId', $catId);
    $this->view->assign('categories', $categories);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can inject every repository of every installed extbase extension. Just add the dependency injection code to your controller. Depending on your TYPO3 version ist either:

**TYPO3 >= 6.0:**

```
/**
 * @var \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\SomeRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $someRepository;
```

Note that the `@inject` Annotation does not perform very well in comparison to a dedicated inject method. So if you need to tweek the performance of your application and have many injections in yout controller you should consider switching to inject methods:

```
/**
 * @var \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\SomeRepository
 */
protected $someRepository;

/**
 * @param \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\SomeRepository
 */
public function injectSomeRepository(\Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\SomeRepository $someRepository) {
  $this->someRepository = $someRepository;
}
```

**TYPO3 = 4.7:**

```
/**
 * @var Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Repository_SomeRepository
 * @inject
 */
 protected $someRepository;
```

**TYPO3 < 4.7**

```
/**
 * @var Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Repository_SomeRepository
 */
 protected $someRepository;

/**
 * Inject SomeRepository
 * @param Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Repository_SomeRepository $someRepository
 * @return void
 */
public function injectSomeRepository(Tx_MyExtension_Domain_Repository_SomeRepository $someRepository) {
  $this->someRepository = $someRepository;
}
```

In any case you can use `$this->someRepository` with all its methods in the controller you injected the repository into.

*Edit: fixed typo.*

Edit:  **After adding a Dependency Injection, you have to clear the cache!**

Comment: My listAction in the code above, is from designController.php. Is in that file I should add

    /**
     * (at)var \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\SomeRepository
     * (at)inject
     */
    protected $someRepository;

Or should I create categoryController.php and add it in there?

Comment: You dont have to create a new controller. Just inject the categoryRepository into your DesignController like you (hopefully) did with the designRepository...

Comment: 'class DesignController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {

 /**
  * designRepository
  *
  * (at)var \TYPO3\OrigKentaurProducts\Domain\Repository\DesignRepository
  * (at)inject
  */
 protected $designRepository;
 
 /**
  * (at)var \TYPO3\OrigKentaurProducts\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository
  * (at)inject
  */
 protected $categoryRepository;'

And: '$categories = $this->categoryRepository->getCategories($catId);'

That gives me "Call to a member function getCategories() on a non-object"

In CategoryRepository.php I have:

'public function getCategories($catId){'

Comment: Sorry for missing line breaks.

Comment: Is your CategoryRepository.php is in the same folder as your designRepository. Make sure they are, you telling extbase they are.

Comment: Then, check the namespaces in both Repositories. It has to be TYPO3\OrigKentaurProducts\Domain\Repository\.

Comment: And after adding an Dependency Injection, you have to clear the cache

Comment: It is fantastic: Now everything works. I thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Glad to help out. Can you mark my answer as accepted then, so the question is marked as answered, please?

Comment: in my case, i needed to deactive/active the extension to make it work