# how to: use Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository in typo3 v4.5

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am trying to read the username of a front end user whose uid is known.  I tried this in my controller's showAction method:

```
$objectManger = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Object_ObjectManager');
// get repository
$repository = $objectManger->get('Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository ');
$newObject = $repository->findByUid($coupon->getCreator()); //this is the uid of whoever was loggin in
print_r($newObject);
echo $newObject->getUsername(); die;
```

but when that code runs I get:

Oops, an error occured!
"Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository " is not a valid cache entry identifier.

It turns out that $repository is empty, so how do I get fe_user data?

I am using typo3 v4.5 with extbase.

Thanks

Update to show complete answer.
This is the code (it goes in my CouponController) that worked (plus the typoscript mentioned):

```
 /** 
     * @var Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository 
     */ 
    protected $userRepository; 

      /**  
       * Inject the user repository
       * @param Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository $userRepository 
       * @return void */ 
      public function injectFrontendUserRepository(Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository $userRepository) { 
          $this->userRepository = $userRepository;             
      }


public function showAction(Tx_Coupons_Domain_Model_Coupon $coupon) {

           $userRepository = $this->objectManager->get("Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository");

            $newObject =  $userRepository->findByUid($coupon->getCreator());

            $this->view->assign('coupon', $coupon);
            $this->view->assign('creatorname', $newObject->getUsername() );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using extbase yourself you dont have to call makeInstance for your objectManager, it's already there (`$this->objectManager`).

anyway, you should inject this repository (see my answer here: [TYPO3 - Call another repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726574/typo3-call-another-repository))

Clear the Cache after the Injection.

You maybe have to disable the recordtype extbase sets for its FrontendUser:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes.Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser.mapping.recordType >
```

Comment: OK, added the injection, now where would I add that config line?  in my extension setup?

Comment: ok added it to setup, cleared caches and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, could you accept the answer, so the question is no longer "unanswered"?

Answer (score 1):

Set the source storage pid where the repository fetches the data from:

```php
/** @var Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository $repos */
$repos = $this->objectManager->get("Tx_Extbase_Domain_Repository_FrontendUserRepository");

$querySettings = $repos->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds(array(123, 567));
$repos->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);

$user = $repos->findByUid(56); // Queries for user 56 in storages 123 and 567
```

Comment: That looks interesting, did you declare the vars $repos and $this->objectmanager  differently than I did in my code frag?  outside of the method?  looks like you made objectManager a member var, but not $repos?   and the numbers for the array, where did you get them?

Comment: i got it working with injection and without the querysettings. i'll update my q with code.

Comment: You can inject object manager like this.. http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/typo3-624-repository-instanzieren/